# Faster excel to json converter than php?

Tags: php, json, excel

I tried using php libraries in order to convert excel to php array, but it uses a lot of ram. Because of this reason I need some tool which would convert excel to json fast and with minimum amount of ram being used in the process. After that I will convert json to php array.

Can you recommend something? I found [this](https://github.com/nullpunkt/excel-to-json). It works really fast and uses small amount of memory, but it does not support UTF-8 which is a must for me.

Any ideas? I am browsing through the web and all I can find are online tools for such a job.

Comment: Must it be done on web? Excel VBA can probably do it quite cheap.

Comment: @Andreas it must be done on the server side